# Obtain the same behaviour of print <<FILE (print <<'FILE') into STDOUT

Tags: perl, printf, stdout

I tried this example:

```
#!C:/Perl64/bin/perl.exe

$mickey = "Hi i'm Mickey";
$pluto = "Hi i'm Pluto";

print <<EOF;
$pluto
Hi i'm Goofy
$mickey
EOF

print <<'EOF';
$pluto
Hi i'm Goofy
$mickey
EOF
```

Obtaining the following output:

```
Hi i'm Pluto
Hi i'm Goofy
Hi i'm Mickey

$pluto
Hi i'm Goofy
$mickey
```

I want to obtain the same behaviour using whitout using `<< operator`. So i tried this other one:

```
#!C:/Perl64/bin/perl.exe

$mickey = "Hi i'm Mickey";
$pluto = "Hi i'm Pluto";

print STDOUT "$pluto
Hi i'm Goofy
$mickey";
```

that actually prints:

```
Hi i'm Pluto
Hi i'm Goofy
Hi i'm Mickey
```

How can I escape EACH perl special char?

I tried using `print 'STDOUT' ...` having not what I was looking for.

Comment: read about quotation in Perl here http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=401006

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes (or `q/STRING/` [quote operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators)) rather than double quotes if you don't want interpolation to happen:

```
$mickey = "Hi I'm Mickey";
$pluto = "Hi I'm Pluto";

print STDOUT q{$pluto
Hi I'm Goofy
$mickey};
```

`STDOUT` is redundant here too, that's the default. `print 'foo $bar';` would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

```
print <<"EOF";   # <<EOF is short for <<"EOF"
$pluto
Hi i'm Goofy
$mickey
EOF

print <<'EOF';
$pluto
Hi i'm Goofy
$mickey
EOF
```

is equivalent to

```
print
"$pluto
Hi i'm Goofy
$mickey
";

print
'$pluto
Hi i\'m Goofy
$mickey
';
```

Note the parallel between the quotes used.

Unfortunately, because the delimiter is present in the literal, you must escape it.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I escape EACH perl special char?

Use "\" to do that

```
my $var = "test";

print "\$var\n";
print "$var\n";
```

Output:

```
$var
test
```